# How to iterate all rows from Google Sheet

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm working with Google Spreadsheets Api and Android Studio. I'm reading info from a sheet, and showing the results into a List View. My problem is that I can only retrieve the info from the first row, but not from the next ones. How can I do that?

I have the next code:

```
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private Exception mLastError = null;

        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {

        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {

            String range = "Sheet1!A2:H";
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            ValueRange response = mService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(spreadsheet_id, range)
                    .execute();
            List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
            if (values == null) {
                //No me deja mostrar toast aqui
            } else {
                for (List row : values) {
                        row.get(0);
                        row.get(1);
                        row.get(2);
                        row.get(5);
                        System.out.println("resultados:" + row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(1));
                    }
                }


            return results;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the sample code on [Reading multiples ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_multiples_ranges)

To read multiple discontinuous ranges, use a [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet), which lets you specify any number of ranges to retrieve:

Here is a sample Java code:

```
List<String> ranges = Arrays.asList(
        //Range names ...
        );
BatchGetValuesResponse result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId)
        .setRanges(ranges).execute();
```

Another thing is try to replace the for loop to:

```
for (List row : values) {
    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
    System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
}
```

You can specify the indices you needed. In the example index 0 to 4.

Hope this is what you are looking for.